# Objective-c , Setting two views of gradient , but only one correct

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, gradient

I have a question. Have any can give me some hint?

I set two View in storyboard.

I build a AbstractViewController, this class is extends UIViewController.

Then my IndexViewController extends AbstractViewController.

My gradient code is write in AbstractViewController.

Code is below.

```
-(UIView *) setGradientView:(UIView *) gradientView initColor:(UIColor*) initColor     andFinshColor:(UIColor*)finshColor
{

    {
        initColor =[UIColor whiteColor] ;

    }

    if( finshColor == nil )
    {
        finshColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:230.0f/255.0f green:230.0f/255.0f     blue:230.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
    }

    CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradient.frame = gradientView.bounds;
    gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[initColor CGColor],(id)[finshColor     CGColor],nil];
    [gradientView.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
    return gradientView;

}
```

Then I call gradient in IndexViewController.
I am write in viewDidLoad.

code below:

```
[self setGradientView:_bgView initColor:nil andFinshColor:nil];
[self setGradientView:_bottomView initColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:10.0f/255.0f     green:10.0f/255.0f blue:1.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f]
        andFinshColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:10.0f/255.0f green:10.0f/255.0f     blue:10.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];
```

The result only _bgView have change color. The _bottomView is not changed.

I'm confuse about _bottomView not changed color.

Have any one know?

Thank you~

Comment: Try this. `[self setGradientView:_bottomView initColor:nil andFinshColor:nil];`

Comment: But I want set other color, not use nil. @@

Comment: I know, it is a test , if it works, it means the error is caused by the color.

Comment: I try to change other color code. It's correct of two view. thank you very much!!

Comment: If you have found the solution, please write it down and accept it. :)

Comment: I found the solution. The code is not problem which I am not set _bottomView referencing outlets.  = ="  thank you , @KudoCC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. The code is not problem which I am not set _bottomView referencing outlets. = =" thank you , @KudoCC